# What does Size of function returns in case of a pointer in c

Tags: c

The following is my code

```
main(){

    char a[2]={'a','b'};
    copy_arr(a);
    int i=1;
    char *s=a;
    printf("s=%d\n and",sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s));
    printf("a=%d\n",sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));
}
```

The output comes out to be
s=4 and a=2
What does size of function returns in case of the pointer.

Comment: It yields the size of the pointer object.

Comment: The size of just that: *a pointer*. (and `sizeof` isn't a function; its an operator).

Comment: Using the `sizeof` operator on a pointer give you the size *of the pointer* and not what it points to. If you have a pointer to some memory, you have to keep track of the size yourself, there's no way in standard C to get the size of what a pointer pointer points to. Also, remember that arrays decays to pointers, so if you pass an array to a function (even if you declare the argument like an array) you will only have a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example

Comment: again with `copy_arr`. What is that?

Comment: OT: It still is `int main(void)` at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s)
```

This returns

```
sizeof(pointer)/ sizeof(s[0]) /* Note that s[0] = *s */

4/1 ( I guess pointer is of size 4 on your system) = 4
```

The other is

```
sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)
```

`sizeof(array)/sizeof(a[0])` which is `(2*1)/1 = 2`

Comment: (2*1)/1 will be good...

Comment: @Shan Thanks felt your suggestion would augment my answer added it